# Account switching in upper left corner of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Switching between multiple Google-accounts just became a 3-click operation in stead of a 2-click operation now that the user-switcher is moved from the top-left corner to the top-right corner.

Is there a way to put this back to the 'old' style?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `chrome://flags`
- search for `avatar`
- disable the **new avatarmenu**